# drawing a contour for n* 1 matrix

Tags: matlab, simulink, contour

I am new to matlab and simulink.

I have a function P which take two inputs distance and velocity (each one as a function)..

I modeled my system in simulink and I wrote the P function in the block called Matlab function since the function has if statement for example ( if v < 0 then P = 1 else P = 1 / v+d ).

The velocity and the distance function are in form of sine and cosine with different frequencies..

Now I added the block to workspace for P, velocity and distance as an array. In the workspace I have array of n*1 for all of the three.

I want to draw a contour for the P according to the velocity and the distance but the contour accept at least a matrix 2*2 ..

How can I change the P to be a matrix without affecting my work and I want to draw the contour for P with respect to the velocity and the distance ??

Comment: Is you problem actually related to Simulink? Do I understand right, that the simulation was alright and you just have problems with the plot OUTSIDE Simulink now? Are you sure you want to use `contour` instead of `plot`?

Comment: yes I want to use contour not the normal plotting.. I don't have a problem of taking the values outside the simulink as I said I used the block to workplace but now I only have arrays of dimension n*1 and the contour doesn't allow for that.. I want to find another way to help me in plotting the contour

Comment: the contour plot requires a surface, which you don't have. You would need P(velocity) for a lot of distances. You actually just have data for a simple 3Dplot (`plot3`) - alternatively you could use a scatterplot with `v` and `x` as axes and `P` to color the points.

Comment: I want one dimensional contour.. I am actually comparing my result with a contour plot so I have to draw a contour.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

1. See which speeds and velocities you have, and define a 2 dimensional grid based on that.
2. Try to give each point on the grid the correct value (based on your simulation output)
3. Use the `contour` function.

Note that drawing a contour mostly makes sense if you have a significant part of the grid covered. Otherwise try `help plot3` as @thewaywewalk suggested.

Comment: how to define a 2 dimensional grid.. you mean like [x,y] = meshgrid (x,y) but I already  have values for x and y.. x and y are array of data of size n *1

Comment: Suppose the range of your x values is 1,2,3 and the range of your y values is 1,2 then you could define a grid as NaN(3,2). Afterwards fill it with all the occurring points.